# Openbravo Fill a combo box with related info

Tags: java, openbravo

In Openbravo I would like to do the following.

```
For a quotation line (c_orderline records ) I would like to link a line to another line.
ie. provide a combo box on the line listing the other lines on the Quote. ie. the combo contains all line noś for the current quotation.
```

This is because I have related lines.

Can you suggest the best way that this can be managed , perhaps with a selector ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with selectors, [Example](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Selector_Example)

Comment: With the selector you cannot use session variables in the where clause. I only want to display in the combo selection the line no.s avaiable for the current order.    In other words C_Orderline.C_Order_Id = @C_Order_ID@ does not work in the HQL where clause for the selector. So  I can only select All order line nos across the OrderLine file and not just those for the Order of the Orderline I am changing.  Any ideas on how combo boxes are filled from tables where values for the where clause are obtained from screen entries ?